# quick way to check Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, combinations

[image]

The answer is $V_{3}=2V_{1}-3V_{2}, V_{5}=2V_{1}-2V_{2}-V_{4}$, I understand the coefficients in the dependencies determined by the non-pivot columns, and it looks like the the position of non-pivot column decides dependent vector, so I can easily know the form should be $V_{3}=..., V_{5}=...$, but how can I decide the independent vector on the right hand side? let's take $ V_{5}$ for example, I wish it could be $V_{5}=2V_{1}-2V_{2}-V_{3}$ but it is not.

Comment: You want to express the non-pivot variables in terms of the pivot variables, which is why you want $V_4$ and not $V_3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson but why $V_{3}=2V_{1}-3V_{2}$ rather than $V_{3}=2V_{1}-3V_{4}$?

Comment: Well, to begin with, $V_3$ does equal $2V_1-3V_2$, and it doesn't equal $2V_1-3V_4$. More generally, what reduced row-echelon form enables you to do is to express each non-pivot variable in terms of the *preceding* pivot variables.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a matrix $A \in M_{n \times m}(\mathbb{F})$ written as

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{v}_1 | \mathbf{v}_2 | \dots | \mathbf{v}_m \end{pmatrix} $$

where each $\mathbf{v}_i$ is a column vector in $\mathbb{F}^n$. Any linear relation

$$ a_1 \mathbf{v}_1 + \dots + a_m \mathbf{v}_m = \mathbf{0} $$

between the vectors $\mathbf{v}_i$ can be written as

$$ a_1 \mathbf{v}_1 + \dots + a_m \mathbf{v}_m = A \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \dots \\ a_m \end{pmatrix} = \mathbf{0}. $$

Performing row reduction on $A$ results in replacing $A$ with

$$PA = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{v}'_1 | \mathbf{v}'_2 | \dots | \mathbf{v}'_m \end{pmatrix} $$

where $P \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F})$ is invertible. Since $P$ is invertible, we have

$$ PA \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \dots \\ a_m \end{pmatrix} = \vec{0} \iff A \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \dots \\ a_m \end{pmatrix} = \vec{0}. $$

This means that any linear relation satisfied by the columns $\mathbf{v}_i$ is satisfied by the columns $\mathbf{v}'_i$ and vice versa. When $PA$ is in row-reduced form, it is easy to read the linear relations satisfied by the columns of $PA$.

In your case, you can see that

$$\mathbf{v}'_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} - 3 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} =  2\mathbf{v}'_1 - 3\mathbf{v}'_2$$

which implies that $\mathbf{v}_3 = 2\mathbf{v}_1 - 3\mathbf{v}_2$. Similarly for $\mathbf{v}'_5$.